# Scraping Dynamically Generated CSS Tags

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping

I'm currently attempting to scrape the item highlighted here:
[screen-shot of HTML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL6dF.png)

This item has the form div class="css-exfvnn excbu0ji", this was easy to scrape initially, but the middle section seems to change dynamically every week or so (Middle section is referring to the characters 'exfvnn' so it may change to div class="css-qfrctt excbu0ji" or some other randomly generated characters.)

Initially, I thought to use regex and re.compile('^css-[a-z0-9]{6,}\040excbu0j1$') worked for finding it or anything that matched this changing pattern, but I then realized nearly every other CSS object on the page uses an extremely similar format. Is there another way to deal with these CSS permutations? Or am I stuck manually editing my scraper any time it goes down due to these changes?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Is the hierarchy of the tags also changing dynamically? Or why do you have to navigate by the class of the tags?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be changing. Any tutorial you could point me at that discusses scraping by hierarchy as opposed to searching for the relevant tag? I have a basic understanding, but I've never had to go in that direction fully as searching for the relevant tag has always seemed more direct.

Comment: I don't know what you're using for your scraping job. But you can have a look at xpaths and lxml. Most browsers let you lookup xpaths pretty easily in the source code of a page. You can access content by specific parameters but also by its position like this `/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]` for example.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, was looking into xpaths, but had a bit of confusion. This gives me a nice idea of how to continue. 

If it helps you provide any other tips, I'm using selenium since the page loads as I scroll and then using BeautifulSoup to parse it.

Comment: Perfect, selenium can handle xpaths. Just use `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` as described in the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath).

Answer (score 0):

Does it's content/text also changes after a week or so?
if not you can use search by its text

`//*[contains/text()='some text']`

also, you can use the absolute path in XPath(this may slower your scrapper)